# Bluetooth headset BOSE QC 35 not detected for pairing on Ubuntu 18.0 LTS

Tags: bluetooth

I am struggling to connect my BOSE QC35 on Ubuntu. I have tried installing/uninstalling bluez and restarting bluetooth services however when I check the logs I see following:

```
May 11 13:50:59 murtuza-XPS-15-9550 bluetoothd[7299]: Terminating
May 11 13:50:59 murtuza-XPS-15-9550 systemd[1]: Stopping Bluetooth 
service...
May 11 13:50:59 murtuza-XPS-15-9550 bluetoothd[7299]: Stopping SDP 
server
May 11 13:50:59 murtuza-XPS-15-9550 bluetoothd[7299]: Exit
May 11 13:50:59 murtuza-XPS-15-9550 NetworkManager[876]: <info>  
[1526035859.8496] bluez5: NAP: removed interface 44:1C:A8:E3:88:D4
May 11 13:50:59 murtuza-XPS-15-9550 gnome-shell[1089]: Error setting 
property 'Powered' on interface org.bluez.Adapter1: 
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.136 
was not provided by any .service files (g-dbus-error-quark, 2)
May 11 13:50:59 murtuza-XPS-15-9550 gnome-shell[1766]: Error setting 
property 'Powered' on interface org.bluez.Adapter1: 
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name :1.136 
was not provided by any .service files (g-dbus-error-quark, 2)
May 11 13:50:59 murtuza-XPS-15-9550 systemd[1]: Stopped Bluetooth 
service.
May 11 13:50:59 murtuza-XPS-15-9550 gnome-control-c[2175]: Error 
setting property 'DiscoverableTimeout' on interface 
org.bluez.Adapter1: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: 
Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying (g- 
dbus-error-quark, 
May 11 13:50:59 murtuza-XPS-15-9550 gnome-control-c[2175]: Error 
setting property 'Discoverable' on interface org.bluez.Adapter1: 
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient 
disconnected from message bus without replying (g-dbus-error-quark, 4)
May 11 13:50:59 murtuza-XPS-15-9550 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth s 
ervice...
May 11 13:50:59 murtuza-XPS-15-9550 bluetoothd[7680]: Bluetooth daemon 
5.48
May 11 13:50:59 murtuza-XPS-15-9550 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth 
service.
May 11 13:50:59 murtuza-XPS-15-9550 bluetoothd[7680]: Starting SDP 
server
May 11 13:50:59 murtuza-XPS-15-9550 dbus-daemon[866]: [system] 
Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' 
unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.153' 
(uid=0 pid=7680 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " 
label="unconfined")
May 11 13:50:59 murtuza-XPS-15-9550 bluetoothd[7680]: Bluetooth 
management interface 1.14 initialized
May 11 13:50:59 murtuza-XPS-15-9550 NetworkManager[876]: <info>  
[1526035859.9808] bluez5: NAP: added interface 44:1C:A8:E3:88:D4
May 11 13:50:59 murtuza-XPS-15-9550 systemd[1]: Starting Hostname 
Service...
May 11 13:51:00 murtuza-XPS-15-9550 dbus-daemon[866]: [system] 
Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
May 11 13:51:00 murtuza-XPS-15-9550 systemd[1]: Started Hostname 
Service.
May 11 13:51:05 murtuza-XPS-15-9550 kernel: [ 2931.126648] Bluetooth: 
hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
```